# Driving directions using Postgis and pgRouting

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, path-finding, driving-directions

I'm looking for a library based on Postgis and pgRouting that will provide driving directions as well as a route between any two given points. The second part works fine using pgRouting but can't seem to find anything that'll provide driving directions from the route output by pgRouting. Does anyone have any idea where I can find such a project? I'd be looking to start a new open-source project to provide such a library alongside pgRouting if anyone is interested or I can get enough traction to start such a project.

Answer (score 2):

Try emailing the [pgrouting mailing list](http://lists.postlbs.org/mailman/listinfo/pgrouting-users), they usually respond pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks, I also did that and you're right, they are very fast and helpful, will probably try putting something together with their help.